# Is there any way to calculate CPU load on current android versions?

Tags: android, linux, kernel, cpu, cpu-load

My actual goal is to the calculate CPU load of the phone. But this seems not possible on Android 8+ devices. Because the access to /proc/stat is restricted on API 26.

So I am trying to calculate my app's CPU load in my app. This can also work on my case. I can access and read /proc/self/stat without any problem. But every post I saw on the internet for calculations needed proc/uptime. Unfortunately, it is also restricted. So the question **is the CPU load calculations possible anymore?**

Answer (score 1):

This is how [neofetch](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch) does it, at least in [the version I'm using 7.1.0](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/blob/7.1.0/neofetch#L2339):

```
cpu_usage="$(ps aux | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum+=$3}; END {print sum}')"
cpu_usage="$((${cpu_usage/\.*} / ${cores:-1}))"
```